# How to communicate with Keithley devices on linux (without NI VISA)?

Tags: linux, interface, instrumentation

Keithley devices let you read/write commands/data over GPIB ([examples](http://www.keithley.com/products/dcac/voltagesource/broadpurpose/?path=2400/Downloads#1)). LabView has dedicated blocks (VIs) for this purpose, and other wrappers such as [PyVISA](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/master/index.html) use the [commercial VISA drivers by NI](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-5.4.1/4629/en/).

Is there another way to communicate over GPIB with Keithley devices *without* NI VISA?

Comment: What the model No. of your devices? IMO, the measurement instruments usually provide several means to let users to communicate with them. Maybe there are other methods beside GPIB. You can always get help from their documents.

Comment: @diverger, my SMU (2400) also provides an RS-232.

Comment: The PyVISA readthedocs page does not exist. Can you share the url where the new documentation is housed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [Linux GPIB](http://linux-gpib.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to control any GPIB instrument.

Unfortunately, not all GPIB interfaces (the board or USB adapter that connects your PC to the GPIB bus) are supported.  The supported hardware list is [here](http://linux-gpib.sourceforge.net/doc_html/x259.html).

The interface is similar to the NI-GPIB library, which is a slightly lower-level (and less general-purpose) interface than VISA.